# Blender 2.93 Denoising Strength settings

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, denoise

In the Blender Documentation there seems to be several settings for tweaking the denoising (see image) [image]

However, inside Blender, the only options are choosing which denoiser, and the amount of samples (as seen below) [image].
Has the Denoising strength settings been removed or moved elsewhere?

Comment: Are you in the right docs for the right blender version?

Comment: Not sure but maybe these settings are not available for optix denoise. Try using any other denoiser type

Answer (score 0):

You're in the manual for the wrong version. The first screenshot you are showing is as it looks in my Blender 2.83.5 and it's located in the *View Layer Properties*.

The second screenshot you're showing looks like my Blender 2.93.1, and there the *Denoising* settings are located in the *Render Properties*.

I don't remember when exactly this was changed, seems like somewhere between 2.8x and 2.9x versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, things seem to have changed between the versions (but I couldnt find out how/why through the documentation.) In the View Layer Properties in 2.93.1 the options shown in the documentation also do not exist, is the answer then that the Denoising Strength options have been removed?

Comment: As I said in my answer, in 2.93.1 the _Denoising_ settings are in the _Render Properties_, **not** in the _View Layer Properties_. And yes, the manual sometimes is outdated because people do not always update everything unfortunately. So it seems they didn't update the screenshot and it's still the same for 3.0 as well. I guess the change was made because they changed the way it works? I'm not sure about that since I don't use Viewport denosing anyway, and for rendering I use the _Denoise_ filter node in the _Compositor_... it's faster and usually gives better results.